# Parse Local Datastore issue - pinning objects deletes existing pointers

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, local-datastore

I have a PFObject called Post which has two pointers to other PFObjects: Place and Image.

I've enabled the Local Datastore. Say we have 4 posts:

```
PostA -> with PlaceA and ImageA
PostB -> with PlaceB and ImageB
PostC -> with PlaceC but no image
PostD -> with PlaceD but no image
```

In my local datastore I have 10 PFObjects. So far so good.

However, when I pin a new PostE to the local datastore, PlaceC and PlaceD are deleted from the local datastore.

Any ideas why?

Comment: how do you pin PostE to the local datastore, might be something wrong with the pointer?

Comment: Do you find a solution? I have the same problem